# Поиск самой длинной строки

Tags: c++, строки, файлы

Необходимо найти *N* самых длинных строк в файле и вывести их в другой файл в обратном порядке.

Как это можно сделать наиболее эффективно по скорости работы и потреблению памяти?

Comment: Тут не решают лабораторные работы студентам.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните в каком смысле эффективно.

Comment: Нужно создать отсортированный по длине список из N строк (изначально пустых), читать файл построчно и если считанная строка длиннее любой из списка - вставлять ее в список. Список становится размером N+1, после чего нужно удалить из него крайний (самый короткий) элемент. По памяти - накладные расходы на список и одну "лишнюю" строку, по скорости вас ограничивает диск.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, отсортировный список - это эффективно? о_О

Comment: @Qwertiy в данном случае вполне, мне кажется. Потому что список формируется сортированным, сортировка на каждой итерации не нужна. И диск все лимитирует по времени

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, асимптотика сортировки O(n*lb(n)), а нормального решения O(n).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Разбейте задачу на подзадачи.

1. Как читать и писать файл со строками? - std::fstream и производные классы
2. Как работать со строками? Как узнать длину строки? - std::string
3. Как работать с набором строк? - std::list / std::vector
4. Как отсортировать набор? - std::list::sort() + шаблоны + компаратор

После 1-2 часов внимательной работы с поисковиком по этим пунктам у вас будет хорошая база знаний для решения этой задачи. Обязательно пишите небольшие кусочки кода **самостоятельно**, не берите готовые примеры - это убивает творчество.

UPD. Вопрос был изменен автором, поэтому обновляю и ответ

Чтобы узнать самые длинные строки в файле, придется прочитать весь файл. Если вы не прочитаете хотя бы одну строку - возможно она и была самой длинной. Проще всего использовать std::fstream + std::list + [std::getline](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)

```
std::list<std::string> list; // Хранилище строк
std::ifstream file("тут ваш путь"); // Файл для чтения
std::string line; // Одна строка для обработки
while (std::getline(file, line))
{
    // обработайте строку
    // например, добавьте её в список строк
    list.push_back(line);
}
```

Теперь у нас есть список из строк. Нам нужно взять оттуда N самых длинных строк. Сортируем по длине строки! Нам поможет [std::list::sort()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/sort/)

Необходимо определить функцию для сравнения двух элементов списка

```
bool compare_by_length (const std::string& first, const std::string& second)
{
    return ( first.length() < second.length() );
}
```

Теперь мы можем использовать эту функцию для сортировки

```
// Сортируем список
list.sort(compare_by_length);

// Нам нужно взять первые N элементов
std::list<std::string>::const_iterator i;
int index = 0;
int N = 5;
// Выводим строки из списка до тех пор, пока есть строки в списке
// и выведено менее N строк
for (i = list.begin(); (i != list.end()) && (count < N;) ++i) {
    ++count; // Увеличиваем количество взятых строк
    std::cout << index << ": " << (*i) << std::endl;
}
```

В итоге мы получим первые N самых длинных строк из файла

Comment: Это не ответ на вопрос

Comment: Формулировка вопроса изменилась после того как я ответил на очень общий вопрос ) Не моя вина

Answer (score 4):

Для решения этой задачи, прямо-таки напрашивается очередь с приоритетом, реализация которой есть в стандартной библиотеке - [std::priority_queue<>](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue).

Все что нужно - определить соответствующий компаратор и следить за размером очереди.

```
#include <functional>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

template<typename T>
void print_queue(T& q)
{
    while(!q.empty())
    {
        std::cout << q.top() << '\n';
        q.pop();
    }
}

int main()
{
    using S = std::string;
    auto cmp = [](const S &a,const S &b)
    {
        return a.size() > b.size();
    };

    std::priority_queue<S, std::vector<S>,decltype(cmp)> q(cmp);

    std::ifstream file("test.cpp");
    std::string line;
    std::size_t N = 5;
    while (std::getline(file, line))
    {
        if (q.size()>N)
            q.pop();
        q.push(line);
    }
    if (q.size()>N)
        q.pop();
    print_queue(q);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Вам потребуется выполнить ровно два прохода по файлу:

1. Чтение строк из файла, запоминание их длин и границ в список, сортированный по убыванию длины.
2. Выбор первых *N* элементов списка, их пересортировка по убыванию начальной позиции и чтение из исходного файла по заранее сохранённым границам.

Нет необходимости явно хранить номера строк и сортировать по ним, так как смещения от начала файла до начала очередной строки (которое мы уже храним для извлечения и копирования в новый файл) также монотонно возрастают.

И ещё. Так как из всего списка, создаваемого на первом проходе, нам потребуется только *N* первых элементов, то нет необходимости хранить весь список. Вместо этого будем хранить только *N* строк, *наиболее длинных на текущий момент* и при 
необходимости вставлять в него новые элементы с вытеснением старых.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <limits>

static const char inFile[] = "in.txt";     // Входной файл
static const char outFile[] = "out.txt";   // Выходной файл
enum {N = 7};                              // Сколько самых длинных строк надо вывести?


struct LineInfo
{
    std::streampos begin;
    std::streamsize length;
};

static bool lengthLessComparator(const LineInfo& a, const LineInfo& b)
{
    // Знак сравнения поменян, потому что нам необходим обратный порядок
    // Также учитываем случай строк с одинаковыми длинами
    return a.length > b.length || (a.length == b.length && a.begin > b.begin);
}

template<class T, size_t N>
static T* end(T (&array)[N])
{
    return array + N;
}

int main()
{
    // Список N самых длинных строк. Сортированность поддерживаем вручную
    LineInfo longest[N];
    LineInfo* longestListEnd = longest;

    // Начинаем построчное чтение
    std::fstream in(inFile, std::ios_base::in);
    bool hasMoreLines = true;
    while(hasMoreLines)
    {
        const std::streampos stringBegin = in.tellg();
        const size_t stringLength = in.gcount();
        // Разделитель также считывается
        in.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        // Первая часть условия не даёт пропустить последнюю строку.
        // Вторая часть не даёт завершиться на пустой строке.
        if(stringLength > 0 && in)
        {
            // Ищем, куда именно надо вставить новый элемент в список (и надо ли вообще)
            LineInfo potentialLine;
            potentialLine.begin = stringBegin;
            potentialLine.length = stringLength;
            LineInfo* const newPosition = std::lower_bound(
                longest,
                longestListEnd,
                potentialLine,
                lengthLessComparator
            );

            // Если элемент должен быть вставлен в хвосте списка, проверяем возможность этого
            if(newPosition != longestListEnd || longestListEnd != end(longest))
            {
                *(++longestListEnd) = potentialLine;
                std::sort(longest, longestListEnd, lengthLessComparator);
            }
        }
        else
            hasMoreLines = false;
    }

    // Теперь выводим строки в новый файл
    std::fstream out(outFile, std::ios_base::out);
    for(LineInfo* line = longest; line != longestListEnd; ++line)
    {
        in.seekg(line->begin);
        in.get(*out.rdbuf(), '\n');
        out << '\n';
    }
}
```