# Сортировка массива по двум полям С++

Tags: c++, struct

Есть массив, в которым храниться данные о 
 геометрических фигур, и именно: код фигуры , цвет , материал фигуры , объем , площадь поверхности и радиус . Нужно отсортировать по площади поверхности и цвету.
Например , я создал 6 фигур ( 2 красных , 2 желтых , 2 зеленых ) , сначала нужно спросить какой цвет нас интересует ( например желтый ) ,  и программа должно отсортировать те фигуры только желтого цвета.

```
struct
figuri{  char kod[5];
      char tvet [15];
      char material[15];
      float r,plosiadi,obiem;
      } sf[100],
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать

Comment: Определяете операторы присваивания и сравнения, затем сортируете стандартным алгоритмом.

Comment: А что делать с зелёными и красными? Как они должны быть относительно жёлтых? Это какая-то не совсем сортировка по двум полям по вашему описанию.

Comment: @VTT не обязательно операторы добавлять, можно ведь и компаратор кастомный в функцию сортировку подставить.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/758227/235436

Answer (score 2):

Один из возможных способов - предоставить кастомный компаратор (функцию сравнения) и использовать его со стандартным алгоритмом `std::sort`. Например, так:

```
std::vector<Fig> figs = // заполняем контейнер фигурами
std::sort(figs.begin(), figs.end(), [](const Fig& l, const Fig& r) {
    return std::tie(l.one, l.two) < std::tie(r.one, r.two); }
```

При этом стоит иметь в виду, что для полей `one` и `two` должен быть предоставлен корректный оператор меньше `<`, поэтому, во избежании неожиданного поведения проще всего сишные строки заменить на `std::string`, или же добавить временные переменные внутри компаратора. Пример для `one` типа `const char*` или массива `char` (а-ля сишная строка):

```
std::sort(figs.begin(), figs.end(), [](const Fig& l, const Fig& r) {
    std::string ls = l.one;
    std::string rs = r.one;
    return std::tie(ls, l.two) < std::tie(rs, r.two); }
```

Comment: а вообше то можно сравнить сами сишные строки     _strcmpi(ls, rs) < 0;

Comment: @ARHovsepyan можно, но тогда придётся отказаться от сравнения кортежей и писать логику вручную.