# Сортировка строк с файла на С++

Tags: c++

Есть файл в котором больше 3к строк, и нужно их отсортировать по количеству символов.
Мой код:

```
fstream file("myFile.txt", ios_base::in);
int* a = new int;
for (size_t i = 0; i <= length; i++)
{
    a[i] = 0;

}
while (getline(file,str))
{
    a[k] = str.length();
    k++;
}
```

Проблема: Тут я только узнаю длинну строк, подскажите что почитать чтобы отсортировать по количеству символов в строке!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Создаёте [вектор](https://metanit.com/cpp/tutorial/7.2.php)
2. Считываете все строки из файла в вектор
3. Сортируете вектор с помощью [`std::sort`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) (передайте 3-им параметром [компаратор](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/758227/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80))
4. Записываете все строки из вектора в файл

Comment: А про компаратор не стоит добавить?

Comment: @MBo да, добавил

Comment: Большое спасибо!